# Azure container instance execution time

Tags: azure-container-service, azure-container-instances

I have created azure container instance, which do some jobs. I have not founded, where
I could see how long azure container instance executes job?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Azure Container Instance will not show you how long your jobs run, you need to do it yourself. For example, you can create a script to run your jobs and write down the start time so that you can calculate the running time.